# HTML верстка таблички. Создание генератора табличек

Tags: html, css, html5

Здравствуйте,

Я начал делать генератор табличек. Этакий графический интерфейс чтоб можно было сверстать html табличку. У меня по ходу дела начинают возникать банальные вопросы. (Да, извините у меня нет знакомых разработчиков). За любые советы буду благодарен.

1. имеет ли смысл делать ячейку th без scope="" ? правильно ли будет, если можно делать th ячейки только  и
2. Сколько tr может быть в thead/tfoot ? один или сколько угодно (1+)?
3. Такие стили как border-collapse, border-spacing, table-layout применимы только к элементу  или еще к каким-то табличным элементам? если да, то к каким?
4. Логично ли оставить возможность делать исключительно ровные (прямоугольные) таблички. Чтоб каждая строка была одинаковой длины. Или причины почему нужны неровные таблички
5. могут ли быть среди табличных элементов любые другие элементы? Я имею в виду,
   в в tbody может быть только tr, а в tr может быть только td, и ничего другого, верно?

Большое спасибо за ответы. Если кто хочет давать критику и советы в моем начинании в дальнейшем - буду рад таким людям. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что вот так:

1. Я думаю, что смысл есть делать `th` без `scope`
2. Сколько угодно
3. `border-collapse` и прочее, насколько я знаю, применяется только к `table`
4. Как таковых причин нет. Тут уже по вашему выбору
5. Сторонние могут быть только в ячейках `td`. У таблицы должна быть всегда одна структура `table > tbody/thead/tfoot > tr > td/th`, но если вы добавите что-то между этими блоками, то браузер сам исправит и вынесет элемент за таблицу

Comment: @StanislavSagan Вам помог этот ответ или нет?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, мне - очень :D